# Add id:s for objs in arr. R.assoc('id', i++) not incrementing i

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am trying to add id:s to objects in an array with Ramda, but the id just equals **1** for every object.

```
let i = 1;

return R.evolve({
    cms: {
        components: R.map(R.assoc('id', i++)),
    },
}, state),
```

I assume that has something to do with the **i++**. One is not supposed to mutate like that with Ramda.

But then, how would I do this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap it in a function, otherwise `i++` is evaluated once and then applied to all your elements.

```js
const state = {
  cms: {
    components: [{
      name: 'Serge'
    }, {
      name: 'Odile'
    }, {
      name: 'Simon'
    }, {
      name: 'Émile'
    }]
  }
};

let i = 1,
    modifiedState = R.evolve({
      cms: {
        components: R.map((element) => R.assoc('id', i++, element)),
      },
    }, state);

console.log(modifiedState.cms.components);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your very fast answer :). That definitely solves the problem because it creates a new function for every iteration.

Comment: It's also possible like this: R.addIndex(R.map)((element, i) => R.assoc('id', i, element)); But it does not look any nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use Ramda's [`addIndex`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#addIndex) like this:

```js
const transform = R.evolve({
  cms: {
    components: R.addIndex(R.map)((comp, i) => R.assoc('id', i + 1, comp)),
  },
})

const state = {
  cms: {
    components: [
      {name: 'Serge'}, 
      {name: 'Odile'},
      {name: 'Simon'}, 
      {name: 'Émile'}
    ]
  }
};

console.log(transform(state))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```